# mvc 5 asp two db context how to allow both migration to true

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

now if you have only one context for database , like applicationDbContext you are only have to run code in package nug >

```
PM>Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ApplicationDbContext -EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

I have one onthor dbcontext named **MyDbContext**  in models, this for my own created models connection and **ApplicationDbContext** is only for user maintenance, because I have applied role not delete on MyDbContext for models relation which if I apply not delete in **ApplicationDbContext** it will distry the user and role identities so I applied in separate DbContext

in DbContext for not delete on relation is :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        }
```

now how I am able to enable auto migration in both context in same project or just not delete for some moduls in **applicationDbContext**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
  public DataContext()
            : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
        }
```

When the database changes, change class as well

It will solve this problem